# .NET (C#) MySqlDbType for char

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I have been working on calling stored procedures from C#, and I am running into an issue mapping a column that is declared as of type "char" in a mysql database to a mysqldbtype in c# (there is no mysqldb.char, and mapping to varchar does not work).  Could anyone provide me with the correct mapping so that I can call this stored procedure from my code? Thank you.

MySQL proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xyz(IN a VARCHAR(8), OUT bCHAR(64))
BEGIN
   SELECT E.b
   INTO b
   FROM Employees E
   WHERE a= E.a;
END //
```

C# code:

```
//get the salt to use with the login hash
            cmd.CommandText = StringLibrary.XYZ; //proc name
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", username);
            cmd.Parameters["@a"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            /*TODO ------>*/cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", MySqlDbType.); // <---------TODO find the correct type here
            cmd.Parameters["@b"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: I store my salts and passwords as binary BLOBs in MySQL.  Not sure what you are doing.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, non-withstanding what this proc is doing, if you happen to know the c# data type that maps to a char, and would like to share; that would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: its a bug that supposed to be fixed: https://lists.mysql.com/commits/3284 but apparently not released... try String as it was the previous enum used..

Answer (score 0):

Use `MySqlDbType.String`. As per the documentation comments [in the source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/f80f3d4a8a2ad26477feee8c66554e4b7ea4cd3b/Source/MySql.Data/MysqlDefs.cs#L244-L247):

```
/// <summary>
/// A fixed-length string.
/// </summary>
String = 254,
```